# How to open additional app windows for a Desktop PWA?

Tags: desktop-application, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I'm working on a PWA. This is a three-part question.

1. For Desktops, I want to **open content** in a **new app window** (non-browser) once the app is installed. Any ideas?
2. If I *can* open a new app window, then how do I make it **part of the same process** and **share data** with it?
3. Alternatively, if I can't make it part of the same process, then how do I **input data** to the **new window**?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I used in solving that

```
function openSame(link) {
    var s=600, 
    l=480, 
    h=window.innerWidth/2-s/2+window.screenX, 
    u=window.innerHeight/2-l/2+window.screenY, 
    g="scrollbars=no, width="+s+", height="+l+", top="+u+", left="+h, 
    n=window.open(link, "", g);
}

// Call the function passing a link
openSame('https://stackoverflow.com')
```